# Can't auto connect to samba drive on login?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, networking, network-shares, samba

I have a old PC running Ubuntu server with samba and for some reason, my mac cannot connect to it automatically on login. I added the volume to the login items in system preferences but every time I start up my computer a prompt would say "Cannot connect to [ip of the server]". When I type the address in Finder and connect manually though, it would have no problem. The other thing is that the server is not "discoverable" in the networks page, I have to connect manually through the IP address every time. How can I fix this? The server has a static IP. Also, if I add a folder from the drive to the sidebar, when I restart the Mac and try to access the drive through the sidebar shortcut, it will disappear when I click on it. Could this be related?

Comment: Umm just a guess: How do you connect to your server? Do you use wireless LAN or vpn or some other non-trivial stuff? Maybe the issue is that required services are not loaded yet when your system tries to mount the location..

Comment: How is your computer connecting to network? Is it via WiFi by any change? If so I bet connecting to WiFi takes longer and you do not have network up when automount is running.

Comment: Both the server and the Mac is connected via wired LAN. It's really weird because I never run into problems connecting it as soon as I startup the Mac but it just won't connect to it automatically.